# Parent - Child SSIS Package Execution

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I have two SSIS packages named `Parent.dtsx` and Child.dtsx.
For simplicity, the child package simply
inserts a row into an oracle table and this .dtsx has `EncryptSensitiveWithPassword` for the Oracle connection.

The parent package has only one task which is `Execute Package Task` which calls the `Child.dtsx`.
The parent package has `ReferenceType = ExternalReference` with the connection pointing to SQL Server that contains both `parent.dtsx` and `child.dtsx`.

`Child.dtsx` runs fine in Visual Studio. I get the row inserted. If I run `parent.dtsx` via a sql agent job, I get an error saying :

> "ORA-01005: null password given; logon denied"

However, If I logon to Integration Service and manually do a `"Child -> Run Package"`, it works fine.  Of course, I get the pop up asking for the password to the package because it's encrypted.

Why can't I run via the `SQL Agent` to execute `parent.dtsx`?  If I change the agent job step to run child.dtsx, then it works.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason is you did not provide the `password` for the package to decrypt the sensitive portion of it (where the credentials are).

To resolve, under the Agent job stem manually edit the command line to provide the password.

[image]

It is recommended to use the `rely on server for encryption` package protection level.

Comment: Still getting the same error.  Also, what i noticed is after entering /DECRYPT mypw and clicked "OK".  I went back to the screen and the /DECRYPT parameter is not there.  is this expected?  Then I decided to logon to Integration Services and did Parent -> Run Package, edited the command line to include /decrypt and clicked "Execute".  It also failed with same ORA error NULL password.  It's definitely calling the Child.dtsx because that's where I have the Oracle connection.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.  I to had enter the pw in the Execute Package task.